Asana webhook FastAPI
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException
import asana
import os
import logging
from asana.rest import ApiException
from fastapi.responses import Response
import hmac
import hashlib
import json
from asana import ProjectsApi
from asana import WebhooksApi
from asana import ApiClient
from asana import Configuration
# Inicjalizacja routera
router = APIRouter()

# Klient API Asana
pat = os.getenv("ASANA_ACCESS_TOKEN")
workspace = os.getenv("ASANA_WORKSPACE")
project = os.getenv("ASANA_PROJECT")
configuration = Configuration()
configuration.access_token = os.getenv("ASANA_ACCESS_TOKEN")
api_client = ApiClient(configuration)

# Inicjalizacja WebhooksApi
webhooks_api = WebhooksApi(api_client)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@router.post("/create-webhook")
async def create_webhook():
    target_url = os.getenv("TARGET_URI") + "/receive-webhook"
    body = {
        "data": {
            "resource": project,  # Projekt, którego będziesz śledzić
            "target": target_url,  # URL, do którego będą wysyłane powiadomienia
            "filters": [
                {
                    "resource_type": "task",
                    "resource_subtype": "milestone",
                    "action": "changed",
                    "fields": [
                        "due_at",
                        "due_on",
                        "dependencies"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    opts = {"headers": {"Asana-Enable": "string_ids"}}

    try:
        webhook = webhooks_api.create_webhook(body=body, opts=opts)
        logging.info(f"Webhook utworzony: {webhook}")
        return {"status": "Webhook utworzony", "webhook": webhook}
    except ApiException as e:
        logging.error(f"Błąd przy tworzeniu webhooka: {e}")
        return {"status": "Błąd przy tworzeniu webhooka", "error": str(e)}


@router.get("/all-webhooks")
async def all_webhooks():
    opts = {"headers": {"Asana-Enable": "string_ids"}}

    try:
        webhooks = list(webhooks_api.get_webhooks(workspace, opts))
        logging.info(f"Webhooki: {webhooks}")
        return {"webhooks": webhooks}
    except ApiException as e:
        logging.error(f"Błąd przy pobieraniu webhooków: {e}")
        return {"status": "Błąd przy pobieraniu webhooków", "error": str(e)}

@router.get("/remove-all-webhooks")
async def remove_all_webhooks():
    opts = {"headers": {"Asana-Enable": "string_ids"}}

    try:
        webhooks = list(webhooks_api.get_webhooks(workspace, opts))
        for webhook in webhooks:
            webhooks_api.delete_webhook(webhook["gid"], opts)
            logging.info(f"Usunięto webhook: {webhook['gid']}")
        return {"status": "Usunięto wszystkie webhooki"}
    except ApiException as e:
        logging.error(f"Błąd przy usuwaniu webhooków: {e}")
        return {"status": "Błąd przy usuwaniu webhooków", "error": str(e)}

@router.post("/receive-webhook")
async def receive_webhook(request: dict):
    global hook_secret

    headers = request.headers
    body = await request.body()

    if "x-hook-secret" in headers:
        hook_secret = headers["x-hook-secret"]
        logging.info(f"Otrzymano X-Hook-Secret: {hook_secret}")
        return Response(content="", status_code=200, headers={"X-Hook-Secret": hook_secret})

    if "x-hook-signature" in headers:
        if not hook_secret:
            logging.error("Brak X-Hook-Secret do weryfikacji podpisu.")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Brak X-Hook-Secret")

        calculated_signature = hmac.new(
            hook_secret.encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
            msg=body,
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()

        if not hmac.compare_digest(calculated_signature, headers["x-hook-signature"]):
            logging.error("Podpis nie pasuje, zdarzenie nie jest zaufane.")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Nieautoryzowane zdarzenie")

        events = json.loads(body).get("events", [])
        for event in events:
            logging.info(f"Otrzymano zdarzenie: {event}")
        return {"status": "Zdarzenie przetworzone"}

    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Niepoprawne żądanie")

Postman Photo:

Im facing challenge, i struggle with making webhooks, im trying different methods. Can anyone clarify for me how to make it over with Asana? Whatever im trying doesnt work, im not sure where is the problem.
Is that problem with the body, ID's or anything else.
Im first time if its up to Asana API and hooks,
Thank You.
Im working on FastAPI and Ngrok

Already solved it. I had just get body from Asana docs. I was trying to send body twice, through script and postman thats why.
